# Possibility to activate addons in Firefox 10 ESR without user permission?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, user-permissions

i'm working in a company there we would like to deploy 'Firefox ESR'. For our developers, we need to integrated some addons e.g. Firebug. The problem i'm having right now is, that Firefox will not activate addons without the explicit permission from the user.
So here's my question: Is it in some way possible to deactivate this behavior, so that the addons will be installed and activated properly?

To make this clear, i'm not trying to do something bad here! I'm just searching for an elegant way to integrated and activated the addons, so that the user do not need to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are referring to the extra dialog that appears asking the user to reconfirm the add-on installation.

How exactly are you installing these add-ons into the user's Firefox?

There is a preference called extensions.autoDisableScopes which you can adjust which will change Firefox behavior with regards to confirming the install of these add-ons.

You can get more information about this preference here:

http://mike.kaply.com/2012/02/21/understanding-add-on-scopes/